# Not able to create a map using SLAM Mapping( Kobuki+Hokuyo UST-10LX)

Tags: ros-kinetic, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ive been trying to run the Kobuki slam package on my Kobuki using a Hokuyo UST-10LX connected over ethernet but after running the kobuki_slam package,in Rviz i keep getting map not received warning. The odometry seems to be working though when i move around using teleop.However,no map is created.

I connect the laser using the following command :

```
rosrun urg_node urg_node _ip_address:="192.168.0.11" scan:=base_scan
```

If I don`t specify the scan= base_scan parameter i keep getting [frame_id] laser does not exist error on the object of Rviz.

Here`s my rqt_graph at execution :

[rqt_graph](https://imgur.com/MCvqYrG)

And here is my tf_tree

[tf_tree](https://imgur.com/1Gdn2t2)

It might not be enough info to go on, but can someone tell me where I am going  wrong with this? Where I should focus on to try and fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/320537/not-able-to-create-a-map-using-slam-mapping(-kobuki+hokuyo-ust-10lx)/) by [ashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40706/ashu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2019-04-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well looking at your TF tree, the error you're seeing is very literal, you don't have a laser frame defined in your TF tree. You need to add one so that a SLAM implementation can transform the laser to base link.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2019-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ashu](https://answers.ros.org/users/40706/ashu/) on 2019-04-08**:
Thanks.That made me realize what was wrong. The static transform was using laser and the slam algorithm was using base_scan. Just had to change them all to laser.